# Can't add a simple POST handler to an ASP.NET Core MVC web app

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

I inherited an ASP.NET Core MVC web app that won't allow me to place a simple `ASHX` handler nor an `ASPX` page in the `wwwroot` folder. Yet in that `wwwroot` folder, I can place plain old HTML files and those work.

But when I try to access (or post to via Postman) an `ASPX` or `ASHX`, IIS reports 404 not found, which really isn't true. The files are there. Everything else in the ASP.NET Core MVC web app works but now I just need something running server-side that can handle a HTTP `Post` request.

[image]

If I hit the following URL in my browser:

```
https://nate-pc-ultimate.com/UCSD-PACE2/Final.html
```

IIS serves it up as expected. And all other MVC stuff is served up as expected. Why won't IIS serve up `ASPX` or `ASHX` from that folder?

I also tried adding a method into a controller thusly:

[image]

...and I assumed that the URL to that would be `https://nate-pc-ultimate.com/UCSD-PACE2/Pay/Final` - but again I get the 404.

What is the simplest way to achieve an HTTP post handler in ASP.NET Core MVC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, ashx and aspx is old asp.net framework feature, inside the asp.net core, we could use Mini API or controller API inside the MVC controller.

The reason why you couldn't access the paycontroller's post method is you use the wrong url for the route attribute, the right url should be `https://domain/Pay/Final/final`.

> What is the simplest way to achieve an HTTP post handler in ASP.NET Core MVC?

I suggest you could consider using the [minimal api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/minimal-apis?view=aspnetcore-7.0) inside program.cs, like below:

```
app.MapPost("/todoitems", async (string json) =>
{
    
    return Results.Ok("aa");
});
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Brando this works great. Thank you for helping an MVC novice. I really appreciate it.